# Ansible Inventory Multi-line Inventory arrays?

Tags: configuration, ansible

I'm trying to write an array in an Ansible inventory file (i.e. hosts.local) but the array seems to have to be all on one line and can't be split upon multiple:

```
[all:vars]
someArr=["This",
    "doesn't",
    "work"]
```

Is there any way of doing this in Ansible inventory files?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way of doing this in Ansible inventory files?

[INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Format) doesn't support multiline. You may find some programming specific workaround but in this scenario, best is to use YAML for inventory. A sample inventory snippet:

```yaml
all:
  vars:
    multiline: [
      "This", 
      "is",
      "multiline"
    ]
    # Or use below style that results the same
    #multiline:
    #  - "This"
    #  - "is"
    #  - "multiline"
  hosts:
    somehost:
```

Have a look at [inventory basics](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups) for more details.